# how to convert from char* to char[] in c

Tags: c, type-conversion

here is a code sample

```
void something()
{
   char c[100];
   scanf("%s",c);
   char c2[100]=c;
}
```

my problem is when i do this assignment an error says that i can't assign

```
char * "c"  to char[] "c2";
```

how can i achieve this assignment?

Comment: wait wait.. are you wanting to assign the data inside of `c` to `c2` or are you wanting to assign the pointer `c` to `c2` ?

Comment: probably-homework? Do we really need this tag? Why not add but-you-never-know-,-it-may-be-work-as-well?

Comment: No, we don't need that tag - tags should NOT be used to express opinions - that's what comments are for.

Comment: i am trying to assign the data not pointer

Comment: BTW, your function needs a name, not just a `void` return type.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll have to use `strcpy()` (or similar):

```
...  
char c2[100];
strcpy(c2, c);
```

You can't assign arrays using the `=` operator.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use strcpy()

```
char c2[100];
strcpy(c2, c);
```

Answer (score 4):

Better practice would be to use strncpy(c2, c, 100) to avoid buffer overflow, and of course limit the data entry too with something like scanf("%99s", c);

Comment: What you said is correct, but some general C advice for other readers:
1. Be careful with `strncpy` since it won't necessarily NUL-terminate. (Not a problem here since both `c` and `c2` have the same number of elements, but OTOH, that also means plain `strcpy` wouldn't be a problem either.)
2. `fgets` would be better than `scanf`. http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Answer (score 3):

`char []` is not a valid value type in C (its only a valid declaration type), so you can't actualy do anything with `char []` types.  All you can do is convert them to something else (usually `char *`) and do something with that.

So if you wany to actually do something with the data in the array, you need to use some function or operation that takes a `char *` and derefences it.  Obvious choices for your example are **strcpy** or **memcpy**